# Windows 10 shows my usb headset as speaker

Tags: windows-10, usb, audio, drivers, headset

I have asked this question from Logitech support and Reddit but no luck. I am desperate. I have owned Logitech G930 headset for 3 years and it has worked fine so far. But suddenly couple of weeks ago my Windows 10 pc decided to show the headset as speakers? Since then the headset G-buttons and 7.1 surround stopped working. I am quite sure this problem is somehow related to windows 10 and the audio or usb driver. What I have done so far:

1. Uninstall logitech driver
2. Delete AppData/Logitech
3. Delete Program files/Logitech
4. Clean registery entry from regedit
5. Reboot pc
6. Install newest driver
7. Try older driver
8. Try even more older driver
9. Uninstall headset from windows manage devices panel
10. Try all usb ports
11. Try unplugging and plugging headset in for 20 times in a row.
12. Get new pair of headset from Logitech RMA support

and yet it doesn't work. The funny thing it worked 3 years. So the problem must be in Windows usb audio driver somehow.

[image]

Comment: What build of Windows 10 are you using?  The next major build of Windows 10 is adding native support for USB sound devices.  If you are using the Insider Preview, and because your sound device is communicating over USB 3.0, the change in the icon is likely connected to this feature addition.  Why is the icon important to you anyways?

Comment: "So the problem must be in Windows usb audio driver somehow." - You have provided literally no evidence to support this claim

Comment: The icon is not important, but after the icon changed 7.1 surround audio stopped working and the logitech software doesn't work anymore. So I think the headphones are not working correctly.  I have plugged the usb dongle in usb 2.0 too because windows troubleshoot said that. I have tried all possible logitech drivers and they sent me new headset so I don't see any other reason than my windows not installing them correctly. Also the headset has worked 3 years so something has suddenly changed and I can' figure out what has changed.

Comment: I could have sworn your question indicate the audio was still working.  Answer the rest of my questions though.

Comment: The audio is working, but for some reason the G-buttons and 7.1 surround doesn't. 7.1 and G-buttons worked 3 years but suddenly I lost the icon and features with it. I have windows 10 build 1607 currently.

Comment: " I have windows 10 build 1607 currently. " - Are you 100% sure of this?  Because what you describe is the EXACT behavior of the built-in USB 2.0 Audio support that exists in the current Insider Preview build, even the name of the device, matches exactly how it used to work in the previous build. ["USB Audio 2.0 devices are now named based on the make/model of the device, rather than using a generic name, in places across the system, for example Device Manager."](https://www.neowin.net/news/here039s-what039s-fixed-improved-and-still-broken-in-windows-10-for-pcs-build-14955)

Comment: I think I was looking the wrong field. My OS BUILD number is 14393.321 So does it make any difference? Anyway the only thing I know is that the 7.1 surround and G-buttons are not working anymore and I cant figure out why.

Comment: Windows 10 build 14393.321, is indeed to the current stable branch, and not a Insider Preview branch build.